# restricting iterations of for each loop

Tags: knockout.js, knockout-2.0

this is a block of code I am using to generate cells in each column.
Is there any way to restrict this loop for first two iterations.

```
<tr data-bind="foreach: activeColumns">
   <td>
      <select data-bind = "options:$root.weightageType" style="font-size: 12px;">
      </select>       
   </td>
</tr>
```

here activecolumn is an observable array representing all the columns of my table.I want to add a dropdown in each column except first two.

Comment: What does your view model look like? It's probably easier, cleaner and more MVVM-like to just add a property in your view model that just exposes those first two items. You could even use a computed property for it.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the [index](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/foreach-binding.html) of the loop using $index, you could use that with an if to only bind for the first two. Otherwise, you could use a [custom binding](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/custom-bindings.html) and have your logic in that.

Just to clarify, you can create a custom binding and pass the index in using:

```
data-bind="text: Name, nameOfYourCustomBindingMethod: $index
```

and then in your custom binder, you can get the index using:

```
ko.utils.unwrapObservable(valueAccessor())
```